# Suspend and hibernate don't work on a hp pavilion dv6

Tags: 11.04, kubuntu, suspend, hp-pavilion, dv6

I just installed kubuntu 11.04 on my laptop which a hp pavilion dv6, and suspend/hibernate don't seem to work. More specifically, when I try to get out of sleep/hibernation mode, the computer does restart but the screen remains black while the fan starts and the computer gets hot. I have to reboot by pressing on the power button.

I was wondering whether anyone has come up with this problem and might have found a fix for it.

Thanks !

F
Edit : here are the files requested
/var/log/kern.log
http://paste.ubuntu.com/651863/

and /var/log/pm-suspend.log
http://paste.ubuntu.com/651865/

Comment: Could you post your `/var/log/kern.log` and `/var/log/pm-suspend.log` on http://paste.ubuntu.com/ and add the links to your question?

Comment: This happens on some HP laptops with certain kernel/driver combinations. What kernel are you using and what is your graphics card?

Answer (score 1):

I used to observe exactly the same problem after I had updated 11.04 ubuntu to 2.6.38-10 kernel's version. The problem resolved when I switched back to 2.6.38-8 version.

Answer (score -1):

Having struggled with this the whole weekend on my HP pavilion dv6, i finally found a solution! Trust me, I have tried every suggestion that can be found on google before this.

What I did was to reinstall windows, update BIOS (download file from HPs support pages), reinstall linux (Linux Mint 14 XFCE). Finally suspend to ram works perfectly!